# In which academic discipline, are authors listed in alphabetical order (exc. mathematics)

Tags: authorship, author-order

I know that pure mathematical journals list authors' names in alphabetical order.

I wonder if there is another academic discipline that lists authors' names alphabetically.

Comment: is there specific problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: This is pretty common in physics too, though conventions differ from subfield to subfield. I'm a cosmologist, and some of my papers are alphabetical while some are ordered by contribution. It tends to be the more theoretical subfields which use alphabetical ordering.